# System.js and Babel not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, babeljs, systemjs

I am developing a web project using ES 6 in combination with the Babel transpiler and System.js as module loader. In all browsers from IE 9 up, that works well, unfortunately I have to support IE 8 though.

In the unbundled file, IE 8 can't even load my main.js file. It fails with the following console message without indicating any line of code.

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [4] SyntaxError: Error loading "main" at http://localhost:8080/assets/js/main.js
Error loading "npm:babel-core@5.8.22" at http://localhost:8080/assets/libs/npm/babel-core@5.8.22.js
expected identifier
```

I am using jspm as a dependency manager. The bundled sfx file built with `jspm bundle-sfx` yields a different error:

```
cannot read property "call" of undefined
```

Here, at least a line is given, it points to the following function of the system.js core:

```
function forEachGlobal(callback) {
 iterateGlobals(function(globalName) {
   if (indexOf.call(ignoredGlobalProps, globalName) != -1)
     return;
   try {
     var value = loader.global[globalName];
   }
   catch(e) {
     ignoredGlobalProps.push(globalName);
   }
   callback(globalName, value);
 });
}
```

indexOf is indeed undefined here when logging it to the console, although it shouldn't, because it is defined earlier in the file.

The only relevant additional info I can give you is my `package.json`:

```
{
  // some metadata
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.15.7",
    "jspm-bower-endpoint": "^0.3.2",
    // some more grunt tasks
  },
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "source",
      "packages": "source/assets/libs"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        // frontend libraries
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.1.13",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.1.13",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^0.9.4"
    },
  }
}
```

Officially, both system.js and babel support IE 8. I couldn't find everyone else with this issue, so I hope someone can help me solving that issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just guessing: are you using jQuery v2.x? These versions do not support IE8 any more.

Comment: no, I downgraded jQuery to the latest version of the 1.11.x branch.

Comment: so while systemjs supports IE8, IE8 does not support ES5. That's probably what's going on. Not sure how to get polyfills for ES5 in IE8